# Joining another table WHILST using ALTER PROC in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, alter, proc

Simple one for you guys.

Lots of threads regarding joining tables etc.  However, I am yet to find one that also involves the ALTER PROC SQL.

My task is simple...

I just have to JOIN a table called 'STOCK_DESCRIPTORS' to the SQL below in order to display it on my database website.

```
USE [ShopDatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stpGet_StockUnitDetails]    Script Date:    09/17/2013     12:03:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[stpGet_StockUnitDetails]
@strStockUnitCode nvarchar(250)
As
SELECT * from VIEWSTOCKUNIT Where strStockUnitCode = @strStockUnitCode
```

I have tried merely adding:
    SELECT * from VIEWSTOCKUNIT, STOCK_DESCRIPTORS
    WHERE strStockUnitCode =    @strStockUnitCode

However whilst this parses successfully, it messes up the .ASP (strStockUnitCode exists on both tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is join the tables together to be:

Make sure you change the * to be the columns you need for your code.  it is bad practice to select all the columns.

```
USE [ShopDatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stpGet_StockUnitDetails]    Script Date:    09/17/2013     12:03:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[stpGet_StockUnitDetails]
@strStockUnitCode nvarchar(250)
As
SELECT 
     * -- change this to be the columns your code needs
 from VIEWSTOCKUNIT a
inner join STOCK_DESCRIPTORS b on a.strStockUnitCode = b.strStockUnitCode
 Where a.strStockUnitCode = @strStockUnitCode
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response,  It works!  The only problem is now is that it interferes with another unrelated SQL (thats not showing now!).